# What does splat operator do with empty list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm building a simple console utilite where user is asked for input and get an output. Arguments are stored in args:

```
$ ls -optional_arg
args = ['ls', '-optional_arg']
```

I had to handle an input when some command is given as the only argument.

```
$ ls
args = ['ls']
```

Slicing out of range with splat operator ('*') when used in the function without parameters works fine, but I didn't find any explanation for this.

```
func_without_param(*args[1:])

dirname
things.zip
```

Can anyone explain me what happens behind the scenes, when we unpack an empty list using splat?

Comment: What's unclear? It simply doesn't send any arguments, as you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `args == ['ls']` then `args[1:] == []`. `func_without_param(*[])` is equivalent to `func_without_param()`.

Comment: I think OP realizes that it's an empty list ("when we unpack an empty list using splat"). They also see that it's equivalent to not sending any arguments ("works fine"). I'm not sure what other information they're asking for.

Comment: Thanks, John, I understand that's about an empty list. just wondering if some specific 'empty' type is passed to a function. Looks like it's just void out there.

Comment: Is your question how does `func()` work? `func(*[])` is literally equivalent to `func()`. Or are you asking how `func(*[])` becomes `func()`?